# Any Inherent Benefits to Using the 'Instance Of' Instead of 'Contains' Pattern for EventEmitter?

Tags: node.js, inheritance, eventemitter

I find that everything I read about EventEmitter (books or internet) uses the inheritance implementation.

Beyond being more convoluted (using Util.inherits, calling the EventEmitter constructor inside the class), you get problems with multiple inheritance (unless you add more convolution) and less flexibility on class-wide events I find.

What's wrong with this picture?:

```
EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function DummyContainer()
{
    this.Events = new EventEmitter();
}

DummyContainer.prototype.ClassEvents = new EventEmitter();

Test1 = new DummyContainer();

Test1.Events.on('Test', function() {
    console.log('Test');
});

Test1.ClassEvents.on('ClassTest', function() {
    console.log('ClassTest');
});

Test2 = new DummyContainer();

Test1.Events.emit('Test');
Test2.ClassEvents.emit('ClassTest');
```

It seems to me that the above is a little more readable, doesn't need any workaround for multiple inheritance (because it doesn't use inheritance in the first place) and as a bonus, allows you to easily make a distinction between classwide and instance events.

Beyond having to type a little more if you don't use it, is there any incentive to use the inheritance way instead of this?

Comment: What is the advantage of having to use `Test1.Events.emit('Test')` instead of what you get with actual inheritance `Test1.emit('Test');`?  I'm not seeing any advantage to avoiding inheritance.  Plus the `Test2.ClassEvents` object just seems wrong.  All instances of DummyContainer will share the exact same `ClassEvents` object.  Is that really what you want and for what purpose?

Comment: I just find the design more approachable/cleaner (no constructor stealing, no use of opaque util.inherits call that beginners have to learn, no need to worry about the multiple inheritance special case by merging properties), though a bit more verbose. 
For the second point, it's just to have global events for the class without having to worry about keeping a specific object in scope/context. I'll admit I haven't yet fully considered all the design repercussions of this. It just dawned on me as an alternative that is made trivial with this design.

Comment: It's the classic design difference between whether your object `"is"` an emitter or `"has"` an emitter.  There are sometimes reasons to choose `"has"`, but you haven't shown any particular reasons here.  Avoiding inheritance because not everyone knows it is silly.  Do you want to avoid all the useful and powerful and core constructs in the language because not everyone knows them?

Comment: Well, my mindset whenever I create something others will use is that while I can do anything that I want internally, externally, the barrier of entry to use it should be as small as possible (whether or not I succeed in that goal, that remains the goal).
I guess in this case, main users of EventEmitter will be library creators who are expected to know more, but when I find myself having to research what util.inherits does or reading about the recommended way to use it when the constructor that uses it already inherits, I'm left wondering if the interface should be simpler.

Comment: `Util.inherits()` is just a utility function for implementing base level prototype inheritance in Javascript (only a few lines of code).  Kind of hard to design good, resuable, reliable, simple code in Javascript without taking advantage of object inheritance and understanding how it works.  It is simply the best tool for solving many design issues.  You are seriously handicapping yourself if you're designing for an audience that doesn't understand basic inheritance such that you won't allow yourself to use such an important tool.